# How to determine if the LDAP server allows anonymous binding or not?

Tags: java, ldap, anonymous

Using java when i try to connect to an LDAP server which does not allow anonymous binding i don't get any errors. But when i use a client to connect to that server anonymously, i am not able to. Is there a way to identify if the LDAP server supports anonymous binding or not in java ?

```
// Set up environment for creating initial context
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"+host+":"+port+"/");     
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
env.put(VsomConstants.LDAP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, SystemPreferencesHelper.getLdapConnectionTimeOut().toString());

env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");

// Create initial context
ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Comment: Just try it? And handle the exception?

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code against a which does not allow anonymous binding, I get:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 48 - Anonymous Simple Bind Disabled
```

I used a method for testing as a wrapper around the code you supplied:

```
try
{
   doSimpleBind(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}
catch (NamingException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not sure what your line of:

```
env.put(VsomConstants.LDAP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,SystemPreferencesHelper.getLdapConnectionTimeOut().toString());
```

Was, so I commented it out.

-jim

Comment: To server i tried to connect, i don't get this exception. That's the reason why i want to know if there is way to check whether the LDAP server allows anonymous binding or not through java ?

Comment: THere is nothing in the LDAP protocol that will allow you to determine if the server allows anonymous binding. You should try this with a known good LDAP client (Apache Studio or command line utilities from your LDAP server vendor) to determine if the server truly is not supporting anonymous binding. Perhaps, it supports anonymous binding but there are no anonymous rights.

Comment: What is the actual difference between anonymous binding and anonymous rights ?

Comment: most LDAP server implementations can determine the Rights are granted to an anonymous bound user based on the setting of Access Controls within the LDAP implementation.